# Can CHMOD Changes affect data from loading to a page?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a linux website where data loaded to the page correctly all the way up until I started screwing around with chmod permission changes.  I was making changes, because a js script I am using wasn't working for uploading and cropping an image, and I thought maybe it was a permissions thing in the image folders.

Anyway...

After I made changes to the permissions, rows of data no longer appear, however, I do know that a connection to the database works, because there is some data that is the username appearing in another section of the page.

I changed everything back to 755 for folders and 644 for files and the data rows just do not appear anymore.

Here's the kicker, the exact same files work fine on a localhost server I'm running on a Windows 10 PC.  Same exact database too.

Does anyone have any idea what I did wrong?  I have confirmed that the files on my localhost server match exactly the files on the website, and the connection for both servers is going to the same MySQL db.

I am truly stumped on this one.

Thanks

Comment: did you look into the error logs of mysql and apache(?)

Comment: Yes, this could break things. Check your logs, verify that you have turned off any caching, and double-check both permissions and file ownership.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm a Windows guy.  I don't know where to look for the logs or if caching is turned off, and I don't know what settings file ownership is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Linux/Apache/Nginx issue, rather than the tagged Javascript/PHP/MySQL.

Both Apache2 and Nginx run as a specific user. The current Apache2 default user is www-data, which is a member of the www-data group. If permissions are changed to disallow this user access to files, they will not be able to be served by Apache.

You should make sure all assets are readable by the user your webserver is using (or one of its groups).

It's also worth noting that permissions on MySQL databases are different to Apache2/Nginx filesystem permissions. Being able to access database data doesn't mean your server's filesystem permissions are correct.

I'd also suggest you use Chrome's inspector to check whether your assets are loading; and check your webserver logs to see what errors are popping up.

Comment: The web host support guy said he did a bulk permission fix, but that didn't help.  I am very new to Apache etc.  I'm a Windows guy normally.  I didn't realize playing around with permissions could screw so many things up.  I have all folders at 755 and files a 644, but I'm still seeing the problem only on the web site and not the localhost.  I also don't know how to make sure caching is turned off.  The support people haven't replied since 2pm today.

Comment: As I mentioned above, check the webserver logs, the errors will be in there. Best of luck :)

Comment: I looked at the error logs and did find the problem.  Thank you very much for the advice.  It was telling me that a js file didn't exist, but it did, however, when I entered a script tag I used a lowercase for one of the filename letters and it was upper.  Thanks again!